# Get tests linked to user stories Azure Devops API

Tags: azure-devops

I need a way to retrieve the tests cases and their results from azure devops but by user stories

I’ve tried using azure api and also odata queries.

Is there a way to get the user stories it associated test cases and the results of the runs ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tested, there appears no API out-of-the-box to list all the test results associated with a test case.

In addition, the data shape in [Test metadata reference for Analytics - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/entity-reference-test-plans?view=azure-devops) doesn't not seem to meet your query requirment.

For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.